# Import NEW data from a CSV to a Google Sheet where the NEW data could be on any new row

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a csv file that is overwritten with a new file each day.

The file contains a table with fields like:
First Name | Last Name | Address etc.

The important aspect here is that the new CSV file will have new data but could be on any row. In fact, there will be rows that have the same person multiple times but with different data in some of the columns.

I have been trying to work out a way to compare the array that is coming into the spreadsheet from the CSV to the current data and then only copy new data when there is a row that doesn't match at all.

So far, I have sketched out this:

```
function copyData() {

  // get hold of the CSV File
  const fileName = 'Imported Data.csv';
  const file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();

  // get the data
  const dataBlob = file.getBlob();
  const csvString = dataBlob.getDataAsString();
  const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvString);

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const allData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (let i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {

    const exists = csvData[i];

    // check to see if the file already exitst
    if (exists.hasNext) {

      console.log('yes');

    }
    else {

      console.log('no');
    }

  }

}
```

I realise that this is totally wrong but you can see that I am trying to see if the row in the array (csvData) is matched to the row in the spreadsheet (allData).

I am sure someone must have a better solution (that actually works) to add new data from the middle of a CSV file.

Sorry for my lack of knowledge on Apps Script.

Comment: what's the structure of your data? if you have a identifier to distinct the row value. before you append the values to the sheet, filter the values first and then return the unique or new values, then append.

Comment: Thank you for this. There is a person code, but this can appear several times on different rows, because the format of the csv has different versions of data in the same column for the same person. So person A might turn up 4 or 5 times with different data in a column on each of those 5 rows.

Comment: If each person id has multiple row, then you go over the each column on the row , then return if different. Create a new array to store the new data or use filter function to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function copyData() {
  const fileName = 'Imported Data.csv';
  const file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
  const dataBlob = file.getBlob();
  const csvString = dataBlob.getDataAsString();
  const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvString);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const allData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // I modified below script.
  const obj = allData.reduce((o, r) => (o[r.join("")] = true, o), {});
  const values = csvData.filter(r => !obj[r.join("")]);
  if (values.length > 0) {
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the duplicated values are checked between `allData` and `csvData`. And, the rows without the duplication are appended to the active sheet.
- This modified script checks the duplicated rows by all columns. When you want to check the specific columns, please tell me.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Thank you for this. I have tested it and, unfortunately, it adds all the rows in the spreadsheet and not just the missing row from the middle. It looks great though. I have to say, I am not too familiar with .reduce so I can't, yet, work out what it is doing.

Comment: @Kahooma Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate `I have tested it and, unfortunately, it adds all the rows in the spreadsheet and not just the missing row from the middle.`. When I tested my proposed script, the CSV data except for the duplicated rows for the Spreadsheet are appended. I thought that this is the result you expect. Is my understanding correct? In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Sorry, I will explain what I require and what I get from the script.

Comment: What I require: The csvData will have new data in it that could be on any row within the data. The script should test allData against the csvData and, if the data is already in the spreadsheet, it should ignore it. If the data is not in the spreadsheet, it should add it to the spreadsheet. I tested this by first importing all the data and then deleting a single row from the spreadsheet. Therefore, when running I should get 1 additional row (the one deleted) but I get all rows apart from the header added. I am sorry if this is my mistake. :(

Comment: @Chris Ash Thank you for replying. About `The script should test allData against the csvData and, if the data is already in the spreadsheet, it should ignore it. If the data is not in the spreadsheet, it should add it to the spreadsheet.`, unfortunately, my proposed script achieves this situation. So I cannot understand your current issue. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: No need to apologise. I just checked it on much simpler data and it does work perfectly. I don't know why the original data, that I cannot share because it is personal user information, doesn't work. I will give you a plus for your amazing script and I am so sorry for making you reply to me so much. I need to find out what is so different about the data I have that makes it not work now.

Comment: @Chris Ash Thank you for replying and testing it again. From `I just checked it on much simpler data and it does work perfectly.`, I could understand that the proposed script worked for the simple sample data. Also, I think that the difference between your simple data and your original data might be due to your current issue. And,  I understood your situation of `I cannot share because it is personal user information`.